# Unable to access Xamarin.Forms.Shapes Namespace and API in Code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a dynamic shape using Xamarin.Forms Shape experimental feature shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/), although it worked in xaml using experimental flags but i need to create paths and shapes dynamically.

Xamarin docs only shows xaml example and there is no API or references to use `Shapes` and `Path` in code behind.

here is my Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="SpotlightTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout
            Margin="0"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Orange"
            Spacing="0">
            <!--  Place new controls here  -->
            <Button
                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                BorderColor="Red"
                BorderWidth="2"
                CornerRadius="50"
                HeightRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="Explore"
                WidthRequest="100" />
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


        </StackLayout>
        <Grid
            x:Name="ShadowContainer"
            Padding="0"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Path
                x:Name="MyPath"
                Fill="#66000000"
                Stroke="Red"
                StrokeThickness="1">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <EllipseGeometry
                            Center="55,55"
                            RadiusX="55"
                            RadiusY="55" />
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="00,00,400,700" />
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried to use `Shapes` and `Path` even added `Xamarin.Forms.Shapes` namespace but i am not able to access the API seems like it is not present in the `.dll` but it worked fine in xaml page, how can i access it in code behind? I am using Xamarin.Forms **4.8.0.1687**

Comment: at a glance, Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Shape appears to be an abstract class you can inherit from.  Create you own custom class that inherits from Shape, then set its Path, etc properties

Comment: @Jason seems like `Xamarin.Forms.Shape` namespace does not exist in code behind it doesn't show Shape API at all, i am not able find anything related to shape in `Xamarin.Forms` namespace.

Comment: Fahadsk I don't know if it was a typo from you but what @Jason wrote is "Xamarin.Forms.Shapes" and not "Xamarin.Forms.Shape" the namespace exists in 4.8.0.1687. Try clean/rebuild or uninstall/install xf package.

Comment: I believe the experimental  flag is also not required in that version.

Comment: @Cfun Yes after removing and adding packages, it is now showing the API thanks, sometimes simple steps can be life saver.

Comment: Your problem was solved by uninstalling/indtalling the package or as the accepted answer says by putting the experimantal flag? Could you confirm if it is working wirhout the flag by removing and rebuild?

Comment: @Cfun No it didn't work without experimental flag, but i have to reinstall package for accessing the api, accepted answer simply provided the code which was useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should set `Shapes_Experimental` flag in your `App.xaml.cs`

```
public App()
  {
     Device.SetFlags(new[] { "Shapes_Experimental", "Brush_Experimental" });
     InitializeComponent();
     MainPage = new MainPage();
  }
```

then you could access it in your code behind in your xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Shapes;

Path path = new Path();
path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromHex("#66000000"));
path.Stroke = Brush.Red;
path.StrokeThickness = 1;
GeometryGroup geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
geometryGroup.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry() { Center = new Point(55, 55), RadiusX = 55, RadiusY = 55 });
geometryGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry() { Rect = new Rect(00,00,400,700) });
path.Data = geometryGroup;
ShadowContainer.Children.Add(path);
```